# Parcel JS v2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syntax-error, parceljs

This seems like such a weird thing. I tried running the same exact WORKING version of my React app on another computer, with the same version of parcel (2.0.0-beta.2) and I get the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" when running my app in dev mode with:
`parcel --port 9898 public/index.html --open`

The issue seems to be in the javascript bundle that parcel outputs to dist/ -folder. There are some invalid characters in a variable declaration, which do not appear on the computer on which the app does work:
[image: Invalid characters]

The picture is taken from VS Code, with UTF-8 encoding. The same encoding as on the working computer.

What could be the problem? I can't even find out the file where the issue comes from because the error is so unhelpful.

Thank you!

Comment: what is the content of the method `d3_geo_areaRingStart()` and are the two computers running the same OS?

Comment: @breezertwo It seems to be some calculations that I use nowhere in my app. Seems to be some geographical calculations (points in an area it seems). My dev computer is using Windows 10 and the error occurs on Windows Server 2019.